# Untypical deserialization from json to object

Tags: java, json

I have untypical class:

```
* @generated

public class Something 
{
protected EList<A> a;  //generated from eclipse emf

 ... (only Strings and Ints)

}
```

I don't have any possibility to modify this class (generated code).

I want to deserialize it in this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException,
                JsonMappingException, IOException {

         AMD converter = new AMD ();

         String json = "{\"id\": \"2\",\ ... \"art\": [ null ]}";

         // converting JSON String to Java object
         A a = (A) converter.fromJson(json);
         System.out.println(a);
   }

   public Object fromJson(String json) throws JsonParseException,
                JsonMappingException, IOException {

         A a = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                       json, A.class);

         return a;
   }
```

Everything works ok (for String, int itp.) but I have a problem with `Elist` type. How can I deserialize this list ?

Comment: I really recommend using gson. In any case, you need to write a custom adapter to handle any complex class that isn't a part of the standard Java language.